# release message sent to deallocated instance, but the instance pointer was not nil

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

Here is the code within one of my methods, where imageRaw is an ivar:

```
if (imageRaw) 
    [imageRaw release]; // error occurs here
    .
    .
    .
if (anImage) 
    imageRaw = [[anImage scaleToFitWithin:maxImageSize interpolationQuality:kCGInterpolationHigh] retain];
```

I have had this type of error occasionally, and I don't really understand it. The only way it is non-nil is by assignment to an instance of the right class, UIImage, in this case.

Zombies are enabled.

All I am trying to do in a case like this is cause the existing instance to be deallocated so I can instantiate and assign/retain a new to the same pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing what's happening here is that at some point in your execution, this method is being called when you have something stored in `imageRaw` but don't have anything in `anImage`. In this case, your object in `imageRaw` will be released but nothing new will be stored to it. This leaves the memory address for the deallocated object in `imageRaw` but the object no longer exists. Then, the next time you run the method, it checks to see if `imageRaw` is non-nil (which it is, since it still holds that memory address), tries to call `release` on that memory, and fails. To avoid this, you can make sure to set `imageRaw` to nil every time you call release on it:

```
if (imageRaw)
    [imageRaw release];
    imageRaw = nil;
    .
    .
    .
if (anImage)
    imageRaw = . . .
```

Comment: Thanks, Sean. I checked my methods in the imageRaw = assignment for any autoreleases, which I think has caused similar problems in the past. I didn't see any. So I am testing with your recommendation. It will take a while to test before I can say to problem is solved, but I'll post back here once I know if this resolved it.